# Evaluate Elementor Form Data and Post it on a Page (Basic Quiz)

Tags: wordpress, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

I'd like to evaluate the answers of an Elementor form on functions.php and would like to display certain elementor templates based on the answers. I can get the data from the page and evaluate it, but I couldn't figure out a way to display the result on the redirected page.

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function ( $record, $handler ) {

    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    if ('form_name' !== $form_name) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }
    
    $a = $fields['a'];
    $b = $fields['b'];
    
    $variableName = NULL;
    if ($fields['a'] == 'answer a') {
        $variableName .= '[elementor-template id="1"]';
    }
    if ($fields['b'] == 'answer b') {
    $variableName .= '[elementor-template id="2"]';
    }   

    $handler->add_response_data(true,quiz_function( $variableName ));
}, 10, 2 );
```

I tried using another shortcode on the redirected page, but I was unable to pass the evaluated data into that shortcode. Not surprised it didn't work, but it was the only idea I had.

TLDR: I want to pass the contents of $variableName to the page my form redirects to.

Comment: I would try to send the required data through `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: @jDawwgy, how would I go about capturing that data and displaying on a page though?

Comment: Submit the information that you have captured with a form using the `post` method on the initial page, then once your on the next page you can retrieve those pieces of data with their name attribute for example if it is a name attribute: `echo 'Hello ' . $_POST["name"] . '!';` will output "Hello {name attribute}!"